# How can I create a shortcut in "This PC" on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, mount, shortcuts

How can I create a shortcut in the "This PC" section in File Explorer of Windows 10?

Like a shortcut of a mapped network location or a folder of mounted drive.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: There's a shell namespace API that allows programs to create items there.  You'll see various backup software doing that, and Google Drive also did for a while.  Shell namespace extensions aren't real files though, and don't have filesystem paths, only shell PIDLs.

Comment: @BenVoigt , I have written countless shell extensions in c++ dating all of the way back to Windows 95.  This question has to do with what a user can do without code or editing the registry.  That specific namespace does not support adding shortcuts without editing the registry directly.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Yes, the user-facing answer is "programs can add items there, but files and shortcuts aren't allowed".  But your earlier comment made it sound like nothing can exist there except drives and "libraries", which wasn't correct even for a user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot add shortcuts under "This PC", you may only add folders.

It would be much easier to add a folder under "Quick access" by
right-click on the folder and select "Pin to Quick access".

If you really want to pin folders to "This PC", use this workaround:

- The folder must first be defined as a network share by right-click,
  select Properties and go to the Sharing tab.
- Once the folder is defined as a network share, right-click "This PC",
  select "Add a network location", Next twice, then enter
  `\\127.0.0.1` and click Browse. Find your share and add it.

Answer (score 13):

You can make a folder appear as a separate drive in "This PC" by using the [subst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc726014(v=ws.11)) command.  For example:

```
subst z: C:\Users\yourUsername\Documents\Whatever\Folder\Path
```

Add a shortcut to run this command to your startup folder to make it apply at each login.

Answer (score 1):

Create a desktop shortcut:

- Right-click on Desktop.
- Select *New > Shortcut*.
- For the location, enter `explorer [location]>*. For example:

  - To open D: drive, enter `explorer D:`.
  - To open a remote shared resource, use [UNC path](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230). To access shared folder *JupPlan* on machine *HAL*, enter `\\HAL\JupPlan`. **N.B.** MS Windows requires *backslashes*, but translates them for network access to other OS.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on harrymc's answer, using `Add a network location` is definitely the easiest way to add shortcuts to folders under `This PC`; but the functionality is not limited to network shares. For starters, you can add a local folder by specifying the path in UNC format:

- `\\<ComputerName>\Path\to\Folder`

  [image]

The folder/shortcut is then added to the `Network Locations` section of `This PC` and double-clicking opens the folder, with the Address bar displaying the namespace path:

- `This PC > TargetFolder`

  [image]

The one drawback at this point is that, if you use the `Copy as path` function for any file or folder, the UNC path is copied to the clipboard, which may be undesirable:

- `"\\JP\Users\keith\Music\ABBA\Hits, Vol. 2"`

But this can be remidied -- once you know where to look and what to do.

When you add a network locaiton using the wizard, the shortcuts are created in the user's `Network Locations` folder which has the path:

- `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts`

It's most easily viewed in **Explorer** by clicking in the Address bar and typing:

- `shell:NetHood`

It's informative to switch to a `Details` view and add the `Attributes` column. You'll see your network locations display a `Type` of **File Folder** but with the shortcut arrow overlay (which is not present when viewed  under `This PC`):

[image]

If you view a shortcut's `Properties` dialog, you'll see it only has two tabs. And, unlike a `.lnk` shortcut to a folder, when you double-click on the shortcut, the target folder is displayed as a sub-folder of the `Network Shortcuts` folder. With a `.lnk` shortcut, the location from which it's launched is irrelevant -- **Explorer** "jumps" to the target folder.

These are *Folder shortcuts*, a clever trick of the Windows shell. If you open **PowerShell** or Command prompt to the `Network Shortcuts` directory, then `cd` into a shortcut-named directory, and then list *all* files, you'll see only two:

```
S C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts> sl ABBA
PS C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\ABBA> gci -Force


    Directory: C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network
    Shortcuts\ABBA


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
---hs-         4/29/2023   8:55 AM             75 desktop.ini
-a----         4/29/2023   8:55 AM           1608 target.lnk


PS C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\ABBA>
```

If you added the `Attributes` column in `Network Shortcuts`, you'll note that all the shortcuts have their `ReadOnly` attribute set -- and that's what tells **Explorer** to process the `desktop.ini` file. So clearing that attribute gives you a chance to examine the files more closely via the GUI:

```
PS C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\ABBA> (gi .).Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'
PS C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\ABBA>
```

Now **Explorer** displays the actual contents of the folder, which allows you to view the contents of the `desktop.ini` file and the properties of `Target.lnk`:

[image]

From `Target.lnk`'s `Properties` dialog, you can change a local UNC path to a `<Drive>:\<Path>` format (edit the Comment field as well). After editing, you can re-set the `ReadONly` attribute:

```
PS C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\ABBA> (gi .).Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
PS C:\Users\keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\ABBA>
```

which restores the *Folder shortcut* to its default behavior. And with `Target.lnk`'s path modified, `Copy as path` now returns a "normal" path:

- `"C:\Users\keith\Music\ABBA\Hits, Vol. 2"`

And once you understand the format, you can create *Folder shortcuts* manually or via script. Also, they can be created/placed in any file-system location. The critical elements are:

1. A `desktop.ini` file with these entries:

   ```
   [.ShellClassInfo]
   CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}
   Flags=2
   ```
2. A `.lnk` shortcut to the target folder, which must:

   - Be named `Target.lnk`
   - Target a file-system location (at least I've had no luck with virtual locaitons)
3. The folder containing these two files must have its `ReadOnly` attribute set for **Explorer** to process the `desktop.ini` info.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool by Winaero which does exactly what you are trying to do:

[This PC Tweaker](https://winaero.com/this-pc-tweaker/)

```
With This PC Tweaker, you will be able to perform the following customizations:

* to add any folder to the Computer/This PC folder. Really any.
* to remove any folder from the Computer/This PC folder.
* to change the icon for any folder inside Computer/This PC.
* to add any shell location like Administrative tools, God Mode, Network Connections
* you can pin or unpin Computer/This PC items from the Navigation Pane of Explorer in Windows 8.1, Windows 8 and even in Windows 7!
* You can remove or add any item from the Folders category inside the Computer/This PC folder.
* to restore defaults with one click.
```