# How to get Nav Pane to stay in Quick Access area?

Tags: windows-10

How do I get the Navigation Pane to **stay on a chosen folder in the Quick Access** (eg. "WorkStuff"), instead of moving down to the Drive that holds the original "WorkStuff" folder.

Comment: Quick Access ,even in Windows 10 fully up to date has folders in the right hand Window and really very easy to find and use.'

Comment: Your description is unclear. It would be best if you added screenshots that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you don't. :(

`Quick Access` doesn't display any subfolders in the `Navigatgion Pane` because it has no subfolders, it's merely a collection of shortcuts. Tricks of the shell available only to `Quick Access` muddy this fact somewhat by displaying the `Properties` dialog of target. The `Recent Files` section is a filtered view of your `shell:Recent` folder, which is nothing but a collection of shortcuts. The `Recent Folders` section, on the other hand, is a virtual folder view of the items seen in the **Explorer** *jump list*, which is maintained by the cryptically-named files found under:

- `shell:Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

But regardless of their source, they behave like shortcuts in that they "jump" to their target's location.

### *"But what about the folders under `This PC` ..."*

While `Quick Access` and `This PC` are both virtual folders, the folders under `This PC` aren't merely shortcuts, they are each virtaul folders themselves, but virtual folders *whose contents mirror the file-system location of the correspoinding usser folder*. Each has its target specified and is added to the `This PC` folder by various entries in the registry.

You could create a sort of custom `Quick Access` by creating a folder of *Folder Shortcuts* which behave very much like the folders under `This PC`. I recently composed an [answer detailing how to create these](https://superuser.com/a/1781557/881098).

Comment: Concise answer. Much appreciated. Thanks so much.